# How to do additional operation when a project has been imported to Eclipse grammatically?

Tags: eclipse, build, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

While importing a project into Eclipse RCP using option "Existing project into workspace", I need to set some preferences based on the configuration in importing project. Are there any extension point available to do additional operation while importing project? or is there any way that I can achieve through code?

I tried to figure out the extension point that would help me by looking at core plugins. But no success yet.

Answer (score 0):

Project specific settings are normally in a `.settings` directory in the project folder. This should be imported.

There is nothing to set non-project preferences (and I don't think import should be doing that anyway).

It is possible that Eclipse CDT has additional options - I don't use CDT so I can't say.